# Hash[] vs to_h, are they the same, and if so which is better?

Tags: ruby, hash

These appear to be identical. Is there a preference, performance differences, etc?

```
Hash[[[:a, 'foo'], [:b, 'bar']]]
#=> {:a=>"foo", :b=>"bar"}
[[:a, 'foo'], [:b, 'bar']].to_h
#=> {:a=>"foo", :b=>"bar"}
```

Comment: `to_h` was introduced later (Ruby 2.0 I think) and considered favorable, all other considerations equal, since it's more consistent with "`class.method`" syntax.

Comment: If you do a little Googling, you can find some interesting (if slightly useful) commentary, *e.g.*, [All about `to_h` in Ruby 2.0](http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2013/03/08/all-about-to_h-in-ruby-2).

Comment: `to_h` is definitely preferred on [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not the same. Both can take an array of arrays:

```
Hash[[[1, 2], [3, 4]]] #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].to_h #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

but in addition to that, `Hash.[]` has more quirky syntax. It can accept elements directly:

```
Hash[1, 2, 3, 4] #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

If you try something in between, you will get unexpected results:

```
Hash[[1, 2], [3, 4]] #=> {[1, 2]=>[3, 4]}
```

And although giving it odd numbers of elements usually returns an error, which will help you in debugging:

```
Hash[1, 2, 3]
#=> ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
```

with certain kind of elements, it will silently return an empty hash (but with a warning), which will be hard to debug:

```
Hash[[1, 2]]
#=> {}
#=> warning: wrong element type Fixnum at 0 (expected array)
```

For this reason, `Hash.[]` is tricky. Since `Array#to_h` has been introduced, there is no reason to use `Hash.[]`. `Array#to_h` is better. The Ruby developers will not remove `Hash.[]` just for compatibility.

Comment: Why does `Hash[[1, 2]]` not return as `{ 1=>2}`? It is not an odd number of arguments, unless it takes the single array as 1 arg.

Comment: @onebree you have explained the reason